# curl file path must be change when using cron jobs in host?

Tags: php, curl, cron

hi i have a php code to send telegram message with bot api.
now i have a problem to use curl to achieve file path.
problem is: when i reload page to send photo message by api it works but when i create new cron jobs in my host it does not send photo .
i think problem is from curlpath of file

```html
<?php



$boturl='https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $botToken .'/';


$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath("upload2/$file")); //first parameter is YOUR IMAGE path
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chat_id , 
        'document' => $cfile,
  'caption' => $matn,
        ];

    $ch = curl_init($boturl.'sendDocument');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


?>
```

where is the problem when using cron jobs?
tnx

Comment: tnx thats true dude :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path instead of the relative.

For example:

```
$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath(__DIR__ . "/upload2/$file"));
```

Because the relative path depends on from where you executing the script.

Comment: tnx thats truee dude :))))